# How can I repeat only a part of a command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I'd like to know if it's possible to just repeat *part* of a command.
I.e. if I do `ls /path/to/somewhere -a`, I only want to remove `ls` and `-a`.

I know that if I do `!!` it repeats the previous command (appending the last command to whichever command you write before it) and that if I do `!$` it includes the last part of the string, but I'd like to know if it's possible to re-use only the e.g. middle part of the previous command.

Comment: Instead of figuring out how to get the Nth argument of the previous command, I would probably just form my command as `la -a /path/to/somewhere` and use `$_` or `!$` to get that last argument.  That would work for any case that doesn't have multiple positional arguments.

Comment: Use `Alt+<digit>` then `Alt+.` to substitute the `<digit>` argument.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sure, use `!^`

e.g.

```
$ ls /path/to/somewhere -a
ls: cannot access '/path/to/somewhere': No such file or directory
$ echo !^
echo /path/to/somewhere
/path/to/somewhere
$
```

Alternatively (incurring an extra keystroke) you could use `!:1`.

```
$ ls /path/to/somewhere -a
ls: cannot access '/path/to/somewhere': No such file or directory
$ echo !:1
echo /path/to/somewhere
/path/to/somewhere
$
```

This is fully documented in the **Event Designators** and **Word Designators** sections of the `bash` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: I had forgotten about asking this question. Amazing explanation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To repeat all arguments of the previous commands instead of only the first: `!:1*`

Answer (score 17):

Expanding on [@steve's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706719/50240) to address your general request:

> I'd like to know if it's possible to re-use only the e.g. middle part of the previous command.

You can use multiple word ranges to re-arrange a prior command:

- `!:x`, to recover the x<sup>th</sup> word, first word is 0<sup>th</sup>
- `!:x-y`, to recover the x<sup>th</sup> to y<sup>th</sup> word, inclusive

For example:

```
$ ls /foo /bar -a /baz >/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo !:1-2 !:4
echo /foo /bar /baz
/foo /bar /baz
```

Note that redirection operators count as *individual* words, so:

```
$ ls /foo >/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo !:3 !:2
echo /dev/null >
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Word selection by index can be further expanded to work for commands other than the most recent:

- `!-n`, select the n<sup>th</sup> most recent command
- `!string`, select the most recent command beginning with `string`

Thus, combining those you can get:

```
$ cat /foo -vet >/dev/null 2>&1
$ ls /bar -a >/dev/null 2>&1
$ cp !cat:1 !ls:1-2 >/dev/null 2>&1
cp /foo /bar -a
```

I tend to think of the command history as an array - rows of commands, columns of words - which makes this kind of navigation natural.

One caution: crafting new commands by suturing parts of old ones can lead to commands having irreversible effect. I recommend placing `:p` on one of the arguments to display the built command, rather than invoking it.

For example: `rm !ls:1-4:p`. This will print the final `rm` command, after inserting the 1<sup>st</sup> through 4<sup>th</sup> argument of the most recent `ls` command.

Comment: Wish I could give two solutions, because this is a very in-depth explanation. Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 5):

Bash has a [`yank-last-arg`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html#index-yank_002dnth_002darg-_0028M_002dC_002dy_0029) command for working with your command history:

> **yank-last-arg (M-. or M-_)**
>
> Insert last argument to the previous command (the last word of the previous history entry). With a numeric argument, behave exactly like `yank-nth-arg`. Successive calls to `yank-last-arg` move back through the history list, inserting the last word (or the word specified by the argument to the first call) of each line in turn. Any numeric argument supplied to these successive calls determines the direction to move through the history. A negative argument switches the direction through the history (back or forward). The history expansion facilities are used to extract the last argument, as if the `!$` history expansion had been specified.

With the default keybindings, you can activate it by pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>.<sup>1</sup>  That copies the last word of your most recent command to where your cursor is.

To copy the *n*<sup>th</sup> word instead of the last word, press <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>*n*</kbd>, then <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>.

I find that this is easier to use and is less error-prone than [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html), since it works interactively.

---

Another way to tweak a previous command interactively is to use the [`edit-and-execute-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#index-edit_002dand_002dexecute_002dcommand-_0028C_002dx-C_002de_0029) feature:

> **edit-and-execute-command (C-x C-e)**
>
> Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands. Bash attempts to invoke `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, and `emacs` as the editor, in that order.

Use the up/down arrow keys to recall the command, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open that command in your `$EDITOR`.  You can then edit the command to your liking, then when you save and exit the editor, it will execute.

---

<sup>1</sup> Depending on your keyboard layout, <kbd>Meta</kbd> could mean holding down an <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, holding down an <kbd>Option</kbd> key, or pressing and releasing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.  The <kbd>.</kbd> is the period or full-stop character, in case you have difficulty reading it here.

Comment: If your terminal doesn't suck, bash line editing is about as good as most editors unless the line gets extremely long.  So just up-arrow, ctr-left-arrow (backward word, although that stops on / as well as space), ctrl-u (kill to start of line).  Or ctrl-a (start of line), meta-d (kill word) twice, once each for ls and -a.  But yes, `meta-.` is by far the best answer for interactive use; I use it all the time for stuff like `mkdir foo` / `cd foo`.  I'm surprised other people posted different answers before this with syntax that's no easier to remember, but you don't see if it worked until run.

Comment: Note that this is in `emacs` mode only. For `vi` mode, see https://superuser.com/questions/18498/last-parameter-of-last-command-in-bash-in-vi-mode

Answer (score 0):

Arrow-up. Then `backspace` to remove a few chars. `Ctrl+A` to jump to start of line, `DEL` to remove a few chars. Visual feedback all the way, no guessing. `Ctrl+E` to jump back to end of line.